# NodeJS-Express Contact Form template refresh in the same section

Tags: node.js, express, contact-form, nodemailer

I have a little problem regarding submitting my contact form. Im using Nodemailer in NodeJS-Express.

Everything works fine except that my contact form is at the bottom of the template and after submitting the form and using res.render (with the "*email sent*" message)the template reloads from top, which is not very user friendly.

Any idea how I can use res.render and stay at the bottom of the template.

Thanks in advance

```
 <form method="POST" action="send">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And the app.js

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        var sentmsg ="email was sent";
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
        res.render("website3dartist", {sentmsg: sentmsg})
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Bascially You cannot use `res.render` without re-render since `res` itself means that server will give you new response which means blinking.

You can delete `res.render` and add `e.preventDefault()` to the `POST` form preventing the page reloads.

Since the only purpose of `transporter.sendMail` is to log the message, just add it to them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately the contact form stays with the same input data. I want an empty form with a message saying email sent. I can achieve this by using res.render but my contact form is at the end of the template so I need a way to load res.render and go straight to the bottom.